# Get the MAX with MULTIPLE CRITERIA and WILDCARD

Tags: excel-formula, max, sumproduct

I have this table and I got to SUM the "Age" values when the criteria "Name=Fred" and "Source=S1".

**Note** that "Source" in F2 is getting everything that starts with "S1" (like a wildcard)

I also need to get the MAX from the "Age" with the same criteria. Can I use MAX with SUMPRODUCT?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table2[Name]=$E$2);--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2;Table2[Source])));Table2[Age])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAX(INDEX((Table2[Name]=$E$2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2;Table2[Source])))*Table2[Age];0))
```